# How to calculate quantiles for a gamma distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution, quantiles

I would like to compute quantiles for a gamma distribution. I found a purported example [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/gam-qf.html) given as

$$\text{quantile}(a, b, p) = \frac{\gamma^{-1}(a, \Gamma(a) p )}{b}$$

where $\gamma^{-1}$ is the inverse of the lower incomplete gamma function and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

Trying this out in SciPy I found that for many values I got `nan`, suggesting something numerical going wrong.

```py
from scipy.special import (gammaincinv, gamma as gamma_function)

def gamma_quantile_function(a, b, p):
    
    return gammaincinv(a, gamma_function(a) * p) / b

gamma_quantile_function(3.8756542398707046, 5349.756221, 0.99) # returns `nan`
```

Is there just a problem with my implementation, or is the math wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but R (`?qgamma`) uses the algorithm proposed by Best and Roberts (1975) https://doi.org/10.2307/2347113

Comment: Your method seems reasonable, so it looks like a Python code issue.  In R  both `qgamma(p=0.99,shape=3.8756542398707046,rate=5349.756221)` and `library(zipfR); 
Igamma.inv(3.8756542398707046,gamma(3.8756542398707046)*0.99)/5349.756221` give `0.001840512`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Gamma incomplete functions: the regularized one and the non-regularized one. The Python function `gammaincinv` is the inverse of the regularized one, so you don't have to include the factor $\Gamma(a)$ in the second argument:

```py
from scipy.special import gammaincinv

def gamma_quantile_function(a, b, p):
    
    return gammaincinv(a, p) / b

gamma_quantile_function(3.8756542398707046, 5349.756221, 0.99)
```

This returns `0.001840512168532855`, which coincides with the output of the R command `qgamma(0.99, 3.8756542398707046, 5349.756221)`.

Comment: It seems I suffered from some [inattentional blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness) while reading the docs. Thank you for noticing and pointing out the regularization.